# Get custom component reference in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-custom-component

I am having custom component like below. and i want to get id of component that we used in html file.

```
@Directive({
    selector: `[myattr]`
})
export class myclass
{
   // want to get reference where myattr defined 
    //#myid
}
```

in html i will define like below

```
<input #myid myattr />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Directive({
    selector: `[myattr]`
})
export class myclass
{
   constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log(this.elRef.nativeElement);
   }
}
```